# EWS FindItems returns only 250 items in Exchange 2016

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2016

I have an application which uses EWS Managed API to search and retrieve items from Exchange server. On one client environment (Exchange 2016 on-premise server), when application tries to search and retrieve items from Archive MailBox folders using AQS query, the API seems to only return 250 items even though folder has more items that meets search query. The pagesize i request is 500, but the response only has 250 items.

Anyone know why FindItems() method only returning only 250 items?

Is there any throttling policy we need to disable? This is for Exchange 2016 Server.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Exchange limits the maximum number of items that can be returned in a single request to 1000. But setting the maximum number of entries to a smaller number results in quicker response times, at the cost of having to send more requests to get all items. So, it seems Exchange admin reduced the max number of items that can be returned in a single request.

Comment: Application is using paging. It requests 500 items per page. But in this client environment, the request for the first page itself returns only 250 items. Total items in view also returned as 250. So its not a question about max number of items in a single request.

Comment: Try to check other Exchange settings. Do you have the same problem with any other server?

Comment: When using our in-house exchange server 2016, we do not have this issue. It's reported only in this client's environment. What specific exchange settings i should check?

Comment: Take a look at the [Limit on number of server search results by exchange](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/8b1fe221-3599-4fe2-a06b-ce6bc198a994/limit-on-number-of-server-search-results-by-exchange?forum=exchangesvradmin) forum thread.

Comment: Update: I was able to even recreate this issue where it limits results to only 250 items in our internal Exchange 2016 server when tested using EWSEditor. It seems to occur when AQS search query includes Date filter. If Date filter is not included, then it returns all items in Archive Mailbox folder.

((Sent:1/1/2019..12/31/2019 OR Received:1/1/2019..12/31/2019)) AND ((Kind:Email) OR (Kind:Meetings) OR (Kind:Tasks) OR (Kind:Notes) OR (Kind:Docs) OR (Kind:Journals) OR (Kind:Contacts) OR (Kind:IM))

Any idea?